# Is it possible to check the current cursor is AFX_IDC_HSPLITBAR?

Tags: c++, mfc, cursor, mouse, mouse-hook

I am tried but no luck. Can anybody know, How to check the current cursor type is AFX_IDC_HSPLITBAR?

My code.

```
HCURSOR current_cursor1 = AfxGetApp () ->LoadCursor ( AFX_IDC_HSPLITBAR ) ;

CURSORINFO current_cursor_info ;
current_cursor_info.cbSize = sizeof ( CURSORINFO ) ;

if (   GetCursorInfo ( & current_cursor_info )   )
{
    if ( current_cursor1 == current_cursor_info.hCursor )
    {
        //here not coming also if current cursor is AFX_IDC_HSPLITBAR.  
    }  
}
```

I need to check other applications cursors too.

Basically I would like to hook the mouse and know which type of cursor is showing.

Comment: I suspect that the only way might be to get the icon's 'image-bits' and compare those...

Comment: Which operand i need to use to compare ('&' , '|' , '^') these operands are not able to use for hcursor .

Comment: I think different applications are using different comctl32 version. So,Those cursor objects are different. How to fix this ?